# Prove Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem using Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, functions

having a hard time proving this using the specified $h(x)$.

> Prove the following version of the Mean Value Theorem using Rolle's theorem:
>
> Suppose $f, g$ are two functions defined on $[a,b]$ that are:
>
> (a) continuous on $[a,b]$,
>
> (b) differentiable on $(a,b)$,
>
> (c) $g(x)$ is never $0$ on $[a,b]$ and
>
> (d) $g(a) ≠ g(b)$.
>
> Then for some $c$ in $(a,b)$
>
> $\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}$
>
> Hint: Consider the function $h(x) = f(x)[g(a)–g(b)] – g(x)[f(a)–f(b)]$.

Apologies for any formatting mistakes as it is my first time using this forum!

I know that I am trying to get to

$h(x)=f(x)-f(a)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}[g(x)-g(a)]$

and then prove using Rolle's Theorem, but I'm stuck at

$h(x)=-f(x)[g(b)-g(a)]+g(x)[f(b)-f(a)]$

and not really too sure how to proceed. If anyone can help it would be appreciated!

Comment: Evaluate $h(a)$ and $h(b)$. They are both $0$. By Rolle's theorem there is $c\in(a,b)$ such that $h'(c)=0$. Compute that $h'(x)=f'(x)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}g'(x)$, evaluate it at $x=c$ and move around the factors that have $c$ to one side.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy: $h(a)$ and $h(b)$ are equal, but in general not $0$.

Comment: @Bernard Compute.

Comment: I did it. I obtain $f(b)g(a)-f(a)g(b)$.

Comment: @Bernard Wrong $h$. You are not using the same $h$ as I am.

Comment: I used the $h $ in the hint.

Comment: @Bernard you are using $h(x)= - f(x)(g(b)-g(a)) + g(x)(f(b)-f(a)).$ However, MoonLightSyzygy is using $h(x) = f(x) - f(a) - \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)} (g(x) - g(a)).$ The confusion was natural because djde used $h$ to denote both of these functions.

Comment: Yep. Just wasting everybody's time with irrelevant comments. Like if the constant value would change anything for Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Sorry just a little confused on what "evaluate $h(a)$ and $h(b)$" mean. As for the h situation I believe it is all the same h. I am starting out with the formula in the hint, I am stuck on the $h(x)=-f(x)(g(b)-g(a))...$ and trying to get to the remaining $h(x)$. Unless the hint meant to consider it in some other way...

Comment: The only thing that you need to do is to check the conditions in Rolle's theorem. Namely, compute its values at $a$ and $b$. Then state the conclusion, which will give you the conclusion of Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Rolle's theorem to the following function: $$H(x) = \det \begin{pmatrix} x & a & b \\ f(x) & f(a) & f(b) \\ g(x) & g(a) & g(b)\end{pmatrix}.$$